# what's the advantage of factory pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the practical uses of Factory Method Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751804/what-are-the-practical-uses-of-factory-method-pattern)
>   [Differences between Abstract Factory Pattern and Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/differences-between-abstract-factory-pattern-and-factory-method)

My current understanding of factory is that it can create object by a input string, say

```
Factory.create("mouse");
Factory.create("hamster");
```

What's the advantage of this pattern over new?

Comment: How would you do this with `new`?

Comment: Another possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751804/what-are-the-practical-uses-of-factory-method-pattern

Answer (score 2):

The Factory patter is useful when you have a groups of objects and only objects from a particular group should be created. Somethign like:

```
abstract UI factory:
   create_window()
   create_button()
   ...

Windows UI factory:
   create_window()
   create_button()
   ...

...
```

In this case instead of tons of `if`s over your code you can once instantiate your Factory and use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a factory when you need to create complex products (i.e. "encapsulate" a complex product creation process), have a single point of control for multiple products, or need to manage the lifetime and/or resources that these products consume from a single point of reference.  In some cases it is too complicated to rewrite product instantiation and handling code with "new", so the factory method ensures reuse and uniformity while minimising potential coding errors.

An example might be say in a visual programming IDE where you are using a toolkit in 2 or more projects open at the same time; the toolkit and it's features would most likely be instantiated by a factory pattern because it is so complex graphically and logically, and it requires careful management of one or more of its instances.

Answer (score 2):

A factory is useful if you want to "harmonize" the creation of different objects (in your example Mouse and Hamster) through a shared Factory. This can be used to (a) abstract away specific Constructor-details for each subclass of a common super class (e.g. Animal in your example) or (b) providing default arguments to a Constructor depending on which type of object (or animal) is to be created.

It can be used to unify the creation of objects sharing a commonality, e.g. in caching: CacheFactory -> Memcache, Filecache, ... Working with each cache is similar, but setting up different caching strategies may differ vastly. When using the factory method you can switch between different caching strategies more easily, at best by just chaning one line of code factory("Memcache", options),without having to worry about the intricacies of the specific backend;

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce dependency (if it matters in your lang).

That is, you can insulate your clients from gobs of heavy `#includes`, compilation times, and dependencies.