# Java : Why sometimes we get new object from method instead creating from constructor?

Tags: java, android, class, object

At many places we get new instance of a class from one of its static method instead using its constructor. Like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Or
SmsManager sm =  SmsManager.getDefault();
```

Is there any advantage of using such techniques?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141178/whats-the-advantage-of-factory-pattern

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 2):

This is the factory/builder design pattern, in which the newInstance is used to make a new instance of a type.

Comment: Something like DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() doesn't necessarily mean a Singleton. Hence the word 'new' in the method name.

Comment: It could be *Factory*, it could be *Builder* as well... It just means we are abstracting the creation of the object

Comment: @TheLostMind exactly!

Comment: I would be surprised and upset if a method called `newInstance` returned an existing instance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Thanks ... I updated the answer for this.

Comment: I would still change the first line if I were you..and the second as well  (as James says):P

Comment: Michel you still need to remove/re-phrase the second sentence.