# Advantage of factory method pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-method, open-closed-principle

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern),

The Factory Method design pattern solves problems like:

1. How can an object be created so that subclasses can redefine which class to instantiate?
2. How can a class defer instantiation to subclasses?

For example, `MazeGame` provides the instantiation capability to subclass like `MagicMazeGame`.

### [image]

where,

```
public abstract class MazeGame {
    private final List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    public MazeGame() {
        Room room1 = makeRoom();
        Room room2 = makeRoom();
        room1.connect(room2);
        rooms.add(room1);
        rooms.add(room2);
    }

    abstract protected Room makeRoom();
}
```

---

Read [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141317/3317808).

Of course, this is a creational pattern, so design should be around simplifying instantiation of a class.

---

My question is,

What is the advantage of *factory method pattern*, introducing `MagicGame` class that provides a template method(`public MazeGame(){..}`) and defer instantiation to subclass `MagicMazeGame` or `OrdinaryMazeGame`?

Is *deferring instantiation to subclass* for only abstracting the below intricacies in a class like `MagicMazeGame`,

```
        Room room1 = MagicMazeGame();
        Room room2 = MagicMazeGame();
        room1.connect(room2);
        rooms.add(room1);
        rooms.add(room2);
```

and provide a uniform creation logic in every class `MagicMazeGame` or class `OrdinaryMazeGame`, as shown below,

```
public class MagicMazeGame extends MazeGame {
    public MagicMazeGame() {
        super();
    } 
    @Override
    protected Room makeRoom() {
        return new MagicRoom(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of using the factory method pattern is that you decouple the business logic of creation of a class from the actual logic of the class, because if you don't have that factory method, every class that you add on your system needs to have a factory method inside, and when you have to change something about the creation you may have to deal with all of that set of classes ( bad for the open-closed principle )

Comment: So, to avoid change something about the creation logic in all of that set of classes `MagicMazeGame` or `OrdinaryMazeGame`, factory method `public MazeGame(){}` is used

Comment: As you said: *change something about the creation*, wiki says the same, *This makes the "new" Operator redundant, allows adherence to the Open/closed principle **and** makes the final product more flexible in the **event of change**.*

Comment: Exactly, whenever you can try to avoid the usage of the new keyword

Comment: Java users, Is this pattern used anywhere in Java SE or Java EE or Spring?

Comment: Spring uses it a lot with beans

Comment: Is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory` & `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` designed using  *factory method pattern* or *abstract factory pattern*? Because spring application does not sub class these two classes and and write any simplified creation logic, as expected in *factory method* pattern.

Comment: Instead, Spring application use a factory class like `BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new            FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));` which looks like *abstract factory pattern* that *provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes*

Comment: Probably `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` is a factory method